# I am getting ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 with np.where function

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I want to change 'not available' value in a df column into 0, and for the rest of the values to change them into integers.

Unique values in the column are:

```
['30', 'not available', '45', '60', '40', '90', '21', '5','75','29', '8', '10']
```

I run the following code to change values to integers:

```
df[col] = np.where(df[col] == 'not available',0,df[col].astype(int))
```

I expect that the above would turn all values into integers, yet I get the value error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'not available'
```

Any suggestion why the code does not work?

Comment: Is this a pandas dataframe? It would potentially be useful to look into the `Dataframe.apply` method.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html   You are looking for this with `coerce`  Or do a replace first, then `astype(int)`

Comment: Is 'not available' the only string that does not represent numbers?

Comment: yes, the 'not available' came with the data. Could I change it to 0 when parsing the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before doing

```
df[col] = np.where(df[col] == 'not available',0,df[col].astype(int))
```

it is neccessary to compute

```
df[col] == 'not available'
0
df[col].astype(int)
```

Latter meaning `int` version for *all* which fails, as `not available` does not make sense as integer, you might avoid this problem by using `pandas.Series.apply` combined with `lambda` holding ternary operator as follows

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":['30', 'not available', '45', '60', '40', '90', '21', '5','75','29', '8', '10']})
col = "col1"
df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x:0 if x=='not available' else int(x))
print(df)
```

output

```
    col1
0     30
1      0
2     45
3     60
4     40
5     90
6     21
7      5
8     75
9     29
10     8
11    10
```

This way `int` is applied only to record which is not equal `'not available'`

Comment: that works . I thought that my statement would turn np.where works like if() in excel.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) instead:

```
df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors="coerce").fillna(0)

>>> df[col]
0     30.0
1      0.0
2     45.0
3     60.0
4     40.0
5     90.0
6     21.0
7      5.0
8     75.0
9     29.0
10     8.0
11    10.0
```

Alternatively to only convert "not available" to 0 and convert the other strings to `NaN`:

```
df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col].replace("not available", 0), errors="coerce")
```

Comment: You should mention that any non digit string will become 0, (not only "not available")

Comment: I think the first statement of the OP says that they have no other strings. But I've provided an alternative.